# pod version 1.10.1 causes bitcode error for pod framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, bitcode

Error log : '/Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-WORKSPACE-gndiytqkskvboveiwrfcbnyuvpgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/vivek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-WORKSPACE-gndiytqkskvboveiwrfcbnyuvpgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking' for architecture arm64

I have added **config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'** in pod --> makes it false

but still facing same error